# Инициализация массива одной строкой Java

Tags: java

У меня есть массив `arr`. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы если я вводил с клавиатуры `321234`, то массив был таким `arr = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String str = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(str.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //Ввод

String s = scan.nextLine();

List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();//используем список т.к размер массива не знаем 

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    array.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))));
}
```

Comment: Почему мы не знаем размер массива?

Comment: @RomanDanilov я ошибся, код выше лучше подходит для этой задачи

Answer (score 1):

Например, так, без использования коллекций:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    int[] array = new int[line.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        array[i] = Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); 
}
```

При вводе "321234" в массив `array` будут записаны все числа из строки.